# C# How correctly control checkbox from another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, checkbox

I'm trying to uncheck checkbox after timer stops. But somehow I receive an error on `OnTimedEvent` method in this part `checkBox1.Checked = false;`:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'checkBox1' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was created on.

There is part of my code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Timers.Timer timeris = new System.Timers.Timer();
    int test = 0;

    public Form1()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Enabled = (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked);

    if (comboBox1.Enabled)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.Enabled)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex < 0)
        {
            comboBox1.Text = "Select from list";
        }
        else
        {
            this.Hide();
            timeris.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            timeris.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(test);
            timeris.Start();
        }
    }
    else
    {            
        this.Close();
    }
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timeris.Stop();
    if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = false; // there I receive an error
    }
    this.Show();
}
}
```

Have you any ideas how could I solve It? If I build application and launch `.exe` file It looks like working successfully, but I got an error while debugging.

Comment: You need to hand it back to the UI thread for work

Comment: Try googling for that error text. Google is your friend.

Comment: @BugFinder how could I accomplish that correctly?

Comment: @Dialecticus I've read about this error and It wrote something about  `delegate`, but I couldn't achieve It working. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Also I've read this thread, but couldn't make working in my case with checkbox.

Comment: System.Timers.Timer raises it's elapsed event on separate thread. If you don't need such threading(from your code I think you do not need it), you should use System.Windows.Forms.Timer class's Tick event to achieve your goal. That event is not raised on separate thread and you wont get CrossThreadException.

Comment: @krw12572 thank you, that worked to me.

Comment: You are welcome :)